# How to parse ET time with moment.js

Tags: node.js, momentjs

Is there a way to easily and correctly parse a link like this one in moment.js?

```
August 21, 2015: 11:40 AM ET
```

I managed to parse it correctly, apart from the `ET` bit (which stands for Eastern Time and it's UTC-4) with the following format:

```
MMMM DD, YYYY: hh:mm tt ET
```

Comment: ET might be EST (UTC-5) or EDT (UTC-4). So "correct" might be ambiguous here.

Comment: @MykWillis: according to `http://time.is/ET` and `http://time.is/EST`, ET is UTC-4 and EST is UTC-5. Anyway, I guess that is beside the point, I just want a way of getting the date with the timezone included in the parsing. + or - 1 hour would be okay.

Comment: @cgf - ET is -4 *right now*, because ET is currently in EDT (UTC-4).  Later, it will change back to EST (UTC-5).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things:

- Time zone abbreviations are not all unique.  See [this list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations).  For example, CST has five different meanings.
- There is no international standard for time zone abbreviations.  Different lists may have different values, and some of those values may be invented and not actually used by people in those regions.  They can also vary by language.
- This particular abbreviation "ET" commonly means "Eastern Time", and applies to the Eastern time zone in North America, particularly US and Canada.  It is a *generic form* of the abbreviation, which encompases both Eastern Standard Time ("EST", UTC-5) and Eastern Daylight Time ("EDT", UTC-4), whichever is in effect for the date in question.
- Another way to represent this is with an identifier from the IANA [tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database).  This particular zone is best represented by `"America/New_York"`.  We can use these identifiers with the [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) plugin to moment.js.

  ```
  var input = "August 21, 2015: 11:40 PM ET";
  var format = "MMMM D, YYYY: h:mm A";
  var timeZone = "America/New_York";
  var m = moment.tz(input, format, timeZone);
  var output = m.format(); // "2015-08-21T23:40:00-04:00"
  ```

  Notice that I did not include any format specifier for the time zone.  Since it is at the end of the string, you can just stop there.  (If it were somewhere else in the string, you could place the text to ignore in square brackets.)

  Also notice that you had a few other differences in your proposed format string than the one I'm recommending.  In particular `tt` works in .NET, but it's `a` or `A` in moment.
- In the above example, you had to provide the time zone externally.  If your input could be from various different time zones, then this won't work, and moment can't help you.  You'll need to get the time zone as another input separately.  Moment doesn't try to recognize time zone abbreviations because of their ambiguous nature I described earlier.
- Also recognize that there are some date/time values that will be ambiguous *within* the time zone.  This occurs in the fall when [daylight saving time](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info) ends, creating an overlapping range of values.  For example, `November 1, 2015: 1:30 AM ET` will occur *twice*, first in EDT, then an hour later in EST.  In this scenario, moment will choose the *first* occurrence - which happens to be the daylight time, not the standard time.